# What is the index of a point on a 3D mesh?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, mesh

When using the MatLab command meshToPet, I am using 3 inputs p (points), e (edges) and t (triangles). The description for the edges as per the website, https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/mesh-data-pet-triples.html, says

"e(1,k) is the index of the first point in mesh edge k."

What does the index of the first point in mesh mean?

Comment: You need to look at the rest of that documentation, including the pictures, to get some context. The quote you provided is meaningless on its own, but overall, the docs are pretty clear. What exactly is not clear?

Comment: It says (index of the first point in (mesh edge `k`)), not (index of the first point in mesh) (edge `k`)

Answer (score 0):

`e` has `k` edges on them. The coordinates of points on such edges are in `p`.

so, for given edge number `k`, `e(1,k)` returns an index. This index is the index of the first of the points (`p`) that define the edge you selected (edge `k`).

to get the actual coordinates of such point, you can do `[xp,yp]=p(:,e(1,k)`, as  "`e(1,k)` is the index of the first point in mesh edge `k`."